# Tcpdump - counting outgoing and incoming UDP packets

Tags: command-line, tcpdump, timeout, udp

Is it possible with `tcpdump` to count (for some set up time) the number of outgoing and incoming UDP packets?

I don't have much experience in `tcpdump`, so an advice how to do that would be very helpful. I read that a `timeout` commend is good if I want to stop a process after some given time, so I was thinking about just stopping `tcpdump` after my time.

But how I can count the number of outgoing and incoming packets and filter only UDP packets?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `tcpdump` (or `tshark`) for this. Instead I'd use `iptables` to count the packets over a period of time

```
# Prepare two sets of counters and set up the rules
#
iptables -N udp_in
iptables -N udp_out
iptables -A udp_in
iptables -A udp_out

iptables -A OUTPUT --protocol udp -j udp_out
iptables -A INPUT --protocol udp -j udp_in
```

You can reset the counters at the start of your period like this

```
# Reset the counters
#
iptables -Z udp_in
iptables -Z udp_out
```

You can read the counters at the end of your period like this

```
# Look at the counters
#
packets_in=$(iptables -nvL udp_in | awk '/all/{print $1}')
packets_out=$(iptables -nvL udp_out | awk '/all/{print $1}')
echo "in=$packets_in, out=$packets_out"
```

You can read a counter and immediately reset it by providing the `Z` flag at the same time. For example

```
packets_in=$(iptables -nvLZ udp_in | awk '/all/{print $1}')
```

Putting bits together, and assuming you've already created the necessary extra iptables chains (see above), you can use something like this

```
# Reset the counters
#
iptables -Z udp_in
iptables -Z udp_out

# Wait 10 seconds
#
period=10
sleep "$period"

# Look at the counters
#
packets_in=$(iptables -nvL udp_in | awk '/all/{print $1}')
packets_out=$(iptables -nvL udp_out | awk '/all/{print $1}')

# Report the results
#
echo "During the last $period seconds we saw $packets_in UDP packet(s) in and $packets_out UDP packet(s) out."
```

Comment: Could you add why you would use `iptables` over `tcpdump`?  There seems to be a lot more setup work (vs a relatively straigtforward setup for `timeout`/`tcpdump`) so I'm wondering what the benefits of your method are.  I'm not saying my answer is better by any means. ;-)

Comment: @MikeA neither method is wrong, and both will deliver the results. I have used `iptables` in this fashion before - to count packets and bytes through an interface over consecutive 24 hour periods. In that scenario I don't even need the `sleep`; instead I can use a daily `cron` entry. I'm aware that `tcpdump` and `tshark` can count packets but I don't know how accurate that is in combination with the interrupt triggered with `timeout`. It might be perfect, or it might drop the last "few"; I simply don't know.

Comment: Good point and interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

`man tcpdump` provides the information you need.  The tcpdump web page also provides a [manpage](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html).

Right in the DESCRIPTION it says that when `tcpdump` finished capturing packets, it reports counts of packets captured, received by filter, and dropped by kernel.

Filtering (which is how you only look for packets of a certain type) can be much more difficult, but the EXAMPLES section should give enough of a clue that the only filter you need is `udp` for your example.

So, once you've figured out the correct filter, use `tcpdump` with `timeout` which will run it for your defined time, kill `tcpdump`, and you will get the count of packets.

`timeout 20 tcpdump udp`

This will run tcpdump filtering for udp and will kill tcpdump after 20 seconds.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that it should be run with `-p` to avoid the overhead of promiscuous mode.